# Serving process on a name, account number and sort code

Tags: england-and-wales, fraud, online, process, service

Suppose one would like to exercise statutory rights against a trader who would like not to honour them and thus force the consumer to resort to small claims court. But all they have is a phone number, (whois privacy protected) website, bank account and sort code, is there any process for obtaining their address from this information?

I wonder if the FCA in particular has any mechanisms set up for this.

Comment: In the UK, companieshouse.gov.uk has the details of every registered company in the UK. A self employed person wouldn't be registered, but every one person limited company will be.

Comment: Okay, but what if they aren't registered as a company? What incentive is there for registering?

Comment: My answer to your similar question is better https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80594/what-avenues-of-recourse-does-one-have-on-a-vendor-from-just-their-phone-number?rq=1

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'm sorry for forgetting about it! @Lag

Comment: Joseph R. Not going down for tax evasion is a good reason.

Comment: Yes @DavidSiegel, apologies. I've tried to vote to close this by marking it as a duplicate of that, but not entirely sure how that whole system works to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Financial Conduct Authority (FCA) is the regulator of the financial services industry in the UK, so it seems irrelevant if the product or service is not a financial product or service.

[From Companies House](https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company):

> You can get some details about a company for free, including:
>
> - company information, for example registered address and date of incorporation
> - current and resigned officers
> - document images
> - mortgage charge data
> - previous company names
> - insolvency information

See also [Citizen's Advice on how to report to Trading Standards](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/get-more-help/report-to-trading-standards/).